# Get columns from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table :

```
ColID Columns
1     SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 FROM MyTab
```

I want to get the column names between SELECT and FROM.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE dbo.Mytab(ColID int,  Columns varchar(max))
> INSERT INTO dbo.Mytab(ColID,Columns)
> VALUES(1,'SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 FROM MyTab')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTRING(Columns, CHARINDEX('SELECT', Columns) +6
> , CHARINDEX('FROM',Columns) - CHARINDEX('SELECT', Columns) - Len('FROM')-2)
> FROM dbo.Mytab
> ```

> ```
> | (No column name)               |
> | :----------------------------- |
> |  Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efc4a0b85bc63e43a7134b7689d4ecd4)*

Answer (score 1):

If this is a query that you need the columns for, you can get them with `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`:

```sql
select name from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set ( @myQuery, @parameters, 0)
```

If it is just a table, you can use `sys.columns`:

```sql
select name from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('dbo.myTable')
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it as a nice table I improved(think so :-) ) the fiddle above

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Mytab(ColID int,  Columns varchar(max))
INSERT INTO dbo.Mytab(ColID,Columns)
VALUES(1,'SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 FROM MyTab');
INSERT INTO dbo.Mytab(ColID,Columns)
VALUES(2,'SELECT Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 FROM MyTab')
```

Query:

```
select m.colid, p.value from dbo.myTab m CROSS APPLY  string_split((SELECT SUBSTRING(m.Columns, CHARINDEX('SELECT',m.Columns) +6
, CHARINDEX('FROM',m.Columns) - CHARINDEX('SELECT', m.Columns) - Len('FROM')-2) ) ,',') as p
```

Result:

| colid | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Col1 |
| 1 | Col2 |
| 1 | Col3 |
| 1 | Col4 |
| 1 | Col5 |
| 2 | Col3 |
| 2 | Col4 |
| 2 | Col5 |
| 2 | Col6 |